# media query not being applied

Tags: css, media-queries

On [this site](http://markthecarpenter.com.au/), I have:

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="header">
            <div class="content">                   
            </div><!-- .content (end) -->
    </div><!-- #header (end) -->

    <div id="menu-wrapper">
        <div class="content">          
            <div class="clear"></div>

        </div><!-- .content (end) -->
    </div><!-- #menu-wrapper (end) -->

    <div id="main">
        <div class="content">
            <div id="content">            
            </div><!-- #content (end) -->
            <div id="sidebar">
            </div><!-- #sidebar (end) -->   
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div><!-- .content (end) -->
    </div><!-- #main (end) -->

    <div id="footer-top"><!-- --></div>
    <div id="footer">
        <div class="content">
        </div><!-- .content (end) -->
    </div><!-- #footer (end) -->

</div><!-- #wrapper (end) -->
</body>
```

and:

a Wordpress child theme style sheet with:

```
@import url("../stealth/style.css");

@media screen and (max-width:940x) {

    #header .content, #menu-wrapper .content, #main .content, #footer .content {
        width: 100%;
    }

}
```

However, `#header .content`, `#menu-wrapper .content` & the rest remain @ 940px wide when the view port is less than 940px.

The media queries are not being applied.

Why is this? Thank you.

Comment: 940x? it should be 940px

Comment: Spot on. Thanks @JosephKhella.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@media screen and (max-width:940x) {
```

is mistake!

```
@media screen and (max-width:940px) {
```

Please fix "px" there.